# CSS elements disordered after minimizing the window

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and I have created a website but after whole work is done my all css elements are getting disordered on screen while minimizing the browser window..how to solve this?
I thought I should have provided the % value instead of pixels value...bt its also not working...
Please Help!
One of the stylesheet having this problem is...

```
.card-panel{
  transition: box-shadow .25s;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #f0f8ff ;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position:absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
  bottom:300px;
  right: 300px;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #708090;
  z-index: 2;
}

body{
  background: #dcdcdc;
}

.profile{
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 33px;
  bottom:40px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  border: 5px solid #708090;
}

.name{
  color: #3299cc;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 60px;
  font-family: cambria; 
}

.profession{
  color: #3299cc;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  top: 16px;
  left: 60px;
  font-family: cambria;
}

span{
  color: #708090;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Try [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Why not go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and create a replica of your markup and css so we can better understand and explain what is it that you are missing

Answer (score -1):

You should try to use any Front-end frameworks like bootstrap, foundation, skeleton, frame etc. This will solve your problem.

As you've mentioned you're new to css, I strongly recommend you to use skeleton or [frame](http://getframe.in)

Comment: Thanks...how much time is  required to learn  about these frameworks...?

Comment: @Himanshu  it's very simple. Just learn a bit about the grid system. It helps you to put your content in desired positions for different screen sizes.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.